# How to get accesstoken in My Bot Using OAuth Prompt in Microsoft Botframeowrk c#

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, botframework, single-sign-on

I am trying to get an accesstoken of an user who is chatting with my bot using teams channel.

I am trying to enable SSO with my teams bot.

**I have created Azure AD app with all the configurations:**

1. Set the Redirect URI to https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect.
2. Created Client secret.
3. Provided email , offline_access, opeid, profile, User.Read Permissions.
4. Exposed an api with Application ID Uri : api://botid-appid, added access_as_user scope and added teams desktop and web application as authorized clients.

**Azure Bot Configuration:**

1. Added Message Endpoint url.
2. Used the same Appid and secret of Azure AD.
3. Created OAuth connection with azure AD and Tested the connection from portal(Working fine) as well.

**Bot code Implementation:**
I am using adaptive dialogs created through BotFramework composer in my bot project code. I added the adaptive dialogs created using composer into the dialogset using dialogmanager.

```
this.dialogManager = new DialogManager(rootDialog)
                      .UseResourceExplorer(resourceExplorer)
                      .UseLanguageGeneration()
                      .UseLanguagePolicy(new LanguagePolicy(defaultLocale));
```

Added regular dialog with oauth prompt into the dialogset which is having Adaptive dialog added before.

```
var oauthPrompt = new OAuthPrompt("OAuthPrompt", new OAuthPromptSettings
        {
            ConnectionName = connectionName,
            Text = "Please sign in to continue.",
            Title = "Sign In",
        });
this.dialogManager.Dialogs.Add(oauthPrompt);
```

I have created the Custom Recognizer class That implements Recognizer class , When User send some message to Bot , Message will be passed to Recognize method , I am checking the accestoken inside it and initiating OAuthdialog if accesstoken is not available .

Bot is able to send the OAuthPrompt to User in teams , Once user logged in and provided Consent , Bot is receiving Signin/VerifyState Activity with Only state value but not accesstoken .

```
{"state":"376363"}
```

How to get the accesstoken.

Thanks in advance:)